# Adding exceptions in blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onblur

I'm making a simple Multiple Choice Question form. I want to put validation that if a user clicks on Question `<textarea>` and clicks somewhere else on page while not entering value in `<input type="text" name="q1_option1">` of options of the question, then the user should get an `alert("Wait, you forgot to enter options for Question 1");`. I tried doing it like this but it's simply not the thing that i want. 
 Here is the `<html>`

```
<div class="right">
  <div class="row" style="margin:5px;">
    <label><strong>Question 1</strong></label>
    <div>
      <textarea name="question1"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span-4"><input type="text" name="q1_option1" value="" class="q1" /></div>
    <div class="span-4"><input type="text" name="q1_option2" value="" class="q1" /></div>
    <div class="span-4"><input type="text" name="q1_option3" value="" class="q1" /></div>
    <div class="span-4"><input type="text" name="q1_option4" value="" class="q1" /></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is `<script>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('textarea[name=question1]').blur(function(){ 
        $('.right').click(function(event) {
            if($(event.target).is('input[name=q1_option1]')) {

                $('#alert_error_message').text('Please enter all options in Question 1!!');
                callalert();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Not working!');
            }
        })
    })
})
</script>
```

Now what is happening in this code, when the user clicks on `<input>` to enter the options, `blur` is fired and user gets the alert.
What i want that if a user clicks on these `<input>` of answers, he should not get the alert, else, the user must get the alert for not entering values in the `<input>` of options!!

Comment: why are your writing click event -  `$('.right').click(function(event) {` inside `blur`? That should be independent..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I'm quite confused about it. What i'm trying to do is when the user leaves the Question 1 area, then i should check where the user has clicked. For this, i thought to check click on main container <div> i.e. `<div class="right">

Comment: nope.. That's wrong approach.. @TusharShukla .. So user will be entering question by himself and answer to it in either of the 4 text boxes right and atleast one textbox has to be entered.. Is this what your requirement is?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao No, actually, it has radio buttons below that i've not mentioned. This webpage is meant for making test papers by teachers and not for students. So i just have to make sure that teacher(user) do not leave any option blank if he is entering a question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/t9k7292z/1/)**

I came up with below approach and I will explain what I am doing with the below code. Check for the inline comments.

```
$(function(){
    var hasFocus=false; //this variable is used to check whether focus was on textarea 
    //when clicked on document
    $('textarea[name=question1]').blur(function(event){ 
        setTimeout(function(){
            hasFocus=false; //on blur set the variable to false but after sometime
        },100);
    }).focus(function(){
       hasFocus=true; //on focus set it to true again
    });


    //A click event on document so that to display alert only if textarea had focus and the
    //targetted element is not radio button
    $(document).on('click',function(e){
      if($(e.target).attr('class')!='q1' && hasFocus && $(e.target).attr('name')!="question1") 
        {
            if(!$('.q1:checked').length) //if any radio has been checked
            {
                //if not checked then display alert
                alert('Please select an option');
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: I checked the demo, it worked fine for the first time but not afterwards!! Also, few things that i did not understand i.e.
1. Why `setTimeout`?
2. role of `hasFocus`

thanks for the help and please don't mind my question....

Comment: Can you explain _worked for the first time but not afterwards_? how are you testing actually.. `setTimeout` is actually used because as soon as the blur happens if we set it to false then our `document.click` event's `if` condition always fails to check whether we had `focus` on `textarea`. `hasFoucs` actually checks whether the blur event of `textarea` has occured..

Comment: i was checking in DEMO and it worked for the first time only i.e. i entered text in textbox, i clicked outside, it gave me alert, i again clicked on Question, entered text, clicked outside....didn't work this time, i reloaded the page, did the same thing, same thing happened. Thought to mention this.

Comment: Now i've checked this with my code as well. It worked perfect for the first time but not afterwards.... :(

Comment: @TusharShukla Check this **[updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/t9k7292z/3/)**

Comment: Anytime..,. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var all_filled = true;
// for each component having class "q1", if the value is empty, then all_filled is false
$('.q1').each(function(comp){
   if(comp.val() == ''){
       all_filled = false;
       break;
   }
});
// if not all input is filled, then do what you want
if(!all_filled){
   // do what you want
}
```

Comment: I did as you said but nothing happened. I actually added this code of yours under blur event of question. Anything else that i may be missing or doing wrong?